# Oracle Optimizer refuses to use my index

Tags: oracle, index, optimization, oracle-12c, statistics

I have a relatively simple query that SELECT data in a table.

```
SELECT l.columnRecovered FROM schema.TABLE l
WHERE (column1 = :a or (:a is null AND column1 is null))
AND (column2 = :b or (:b is null AND column2 is null))
AND (column3 = :c or (:c is null AND column3 is null));
```

This generates the following plan :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |       |       |   309 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE     |     1 |    56 |   309   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter((("COLUMN2"=:3 OR ("COLUMN2" IS NULL AND :4 IS NULL)) AND
              ("COLUMN1"=:1 OR ("COLUMN1" IS NULL AND :2 IS NULL)) AND ((:6 IS NULL
              AND "COLUMN3" IS NULL) OR "COLUMN3"=:5)))
```

On this table, I have a UNIQUE INDEX that contains all those 3 columns.
But the optimizer prefer doing a FULL SCAN on the table rather than using the INDEX.

Where things become to go strange, is when I try this query without my binds but by replacing the values directly in the query.
Of course the SQL_ID changes, but this time the optimizer decides to use the INDEX and goes from 1104 gets to 6 (which is of course a great optimization).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |               |     1 |    56 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE         |     1 |    56 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | TABLE_IDX     |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("COLUMN3"='DATA3' AND "COLUMN2"='DATA2' AND "COLUMN1"='DATA1')
```

Statistics are up to date and there are no histograms on this table.

Any way to make the optimizer use that index without modifying the query ?

I think the optimizer thinks that the possibility to have 3 NULLs might happen so this disable him from using the index is it right ?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |     1 |    56 |   199   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE     |     1 |    56 |   199   (2)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMN2" IS NULL AND "COLUMN1" IS NULL AND "COLUMN3" IS
              NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimizer does not use your index, not because it does not want to, but becasue it can not. For a query like that the index does not cover all possible outcomes.

When `:a`, `:b`, `:c` are all NULL, and you are searching for rows where `column1`, `column2`, `column3` are all NULL, those rows are not indexed by a `(column1, column2, column3)` b-tree index, so it can not be used for retreiving the matching rows.

Adding `NOT NULL` constraints may help, but if you have NULL values, that is of course not possible (and I am assuming you have NULL values, otherwise why would you construct a query like this).

You could also try creating an index that includes a constant value, so even those rows will be indexed, where the indexed columns are NULL. So instead of an `(column1, column2, column3)` index, you could try creating a `(column1, column2, column3, 'A')` index.

The best solution in my opinion is however to have different queries generated whenever a bind variable was not assigned a value. Queries like the above are results of trying to handle multiple cases with a single query. This may seem to be elegant and compact, and yes, I know, generating different queries based on the presence of parameters can be cumbersome, but I have seen this kind of laziness causing severe performance issues countless times.

Yes, Oracle has some tricks such as NVL optimization, OR-expansion, for handling such predicates. Those work perfectly in Powerpoint and training materials, with simple examples, but in reality, with complex queries they can not be always used.

Comment: Thanks the index with a dummy value worked perfectly :)